# Android Nested dialog - Specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to display a nested dialog with a back button on the second dialog click on which the user is shown the first dialog. My code is as follows:

```
public class FileOpenMenuDelegate {
    AlertDialog.Builder fileOpenBuilderFolder = null;
    AlertDialog fileOpenBuilderFolderDialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder fileOpenBuilder = null;
    AlertDialog fileOpenBuilderDialog = null;

    public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        selectedItem = position;
    }

    public FileOpenMenuDelegate(Context context, View view) {
        this.context = context;
        this.view = view;
        fileOpenBuilderFolder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        fileOpenBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    }

    public void fileOpenMenu() {

        final CharSequence[] foldernames = getAllFolders();


        if (foldernames == null) {
            //Handle
        } else {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list_layout, null);

            ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listExample);

            selectedAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, 0, Arrays.asList(foldernames));
            lv.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);

            fileOpenBuilderFolder.setTitle(FAC.OPEN_FOLDERS);
            fileOpenBuilderFolder.setView(convertView);

            selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(2);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    fileOpenBuilderFolderDialog.dismiss();
                    selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position - 1);

                    String selectedFolder = foldernames[position].toString();

                    //Sub window

                    final CharSequence[] allFiles = getAllFiles();

                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list_layout, null);
                    ListView subListView = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listExample);
                    fileOpenBuilder.setTitle("Test");

                    subMenuAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, 0, Arrays.asList(allFiles));
                    subListView.setAdapter(subMenuAdapter);

                    fileOpenBuilder.setView(convertView);

                    subListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            fileOpenBuilderDialog.dismiss();
                            if (position == 0) {
                                fileOpenBuilderFolderDialog.dismiss();
                                fileOpenBuilderFolderDialog = fileOpenBuilderFolder.create();
                                fileOpenBuilderFolderDialog.show();************Error Line***************
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    fileOpenBuilderDialog = fileOpenBuilder.create();
                    fileOpenBuilderDialog.show();
                }
            });

        }

        fileOpenBuilderFolderDialog = fileOpenBuilderFolder.create();
        fileOpenBuilderFolderDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Everything works fine except when i click the first item in the second alert, i have written the code of showing the first dialog again - which gives me the error "the specified child already has a parent error". What am i doing wrong ? please help.

Exception log::

```
            02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3672)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3543)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3519)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:402)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:242)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:375)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:261)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at edu.delegates.FileOpenMenuDelegate$2$1.onItemClick(FileOpenMenuDelegate.java:196)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1287)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3078)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4161)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    02-17 12:38:59.250: E/AndroidRuntime(27702):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why dismiss and show the dialogs? Why not just let the second dialog cover the first? Then, on dismissing the second dialog, the first dialog will already be there without any logic on your end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since list view is the child of the first alert dialog, i got the error. I fixed it using

```
((ViewGroup) mainListView.getParent()).removeView(mainListView);
```

Before creating the new dialog. This was the fix for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add `View` which already has a parent. What is here?

```
at edu.asu.fact.delegates
   .FileOpenMenuDelegate$2$1
   .onItemClick(FileOpenMenuDelegate.java:196)
```

**EDIT**

There is no need to keep `AlertDialog` and `AlertDialog.Builder` variables as class members. Try to create them locally each time you need.

Comment: I have updated the error line in the question. The line in which the exception occurs is
fileOpenBuilderFolderDialog.show();

Comment: I've made an edit, please try this solution and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The reason i kept those variables at the class level was, if its local then it has to be final to use them inside the list view onclick method. That means i cannot use fileOpenBuilderDialog = fileOpenBuilder.create(); wherever i want as it has to be initialized at the start.